# firebase firestore emulator not importing all documents

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I have a project `my-proj` in firebase with a firestore database with 153k documents and 50Mb.

I used `gcloud` cli to export my current firestore in production to a bucket:

```
gcloud firestore export gs://my-proj.appspot.com/backup
```

It created a folder in the `gs://my-proj.appspot.com/` bucket with a `backup.overall_export_metadata` and a `all_namespaces` folder.

I can go to gcloud web interface and check that the saved bucket/directory has 153K documents and uses 50Mb.

I then go to my project folder and run the cli command:

```
gsutil -m cp -r gs://my-proj.appspot.com/backup ./data
Copying gs://my-proj.appspot.com/backup/all_namespaces/all_kinds/all_namespaces_all_kinds.export_metadata...
Copying gs://my-proj.appspot.com/backup/all_namespaces/all_kinds/output-2... 
...
Copying gs://my-proj.appspot.com/backup/all_namespaces/all_kinds/output-7... 
/ [10/10 files][ 52.2 MiB/ 52.2 MiB] 100% Done                                  
Operation completed over 10 objects/52.2 MiB.
```

Also...

```
❯ du -h ./data/backup
 56M    ./data/backup/all_namespaces/all_kinds
 56M    ./data/backup/all_namespaces
 56M    ./data/backup
```

So, it copied 56M of data from the cloud bucket to my local folder and I suppose there are 153K documents there.

I then start my firestore emulator with:

```
firebase emulators:start --import ./data/backup
```

Emulators start...

I can then go to `localhost:4000` > Firestore Emulator > Go to emulator.
In the emulator all collections are there, except the one with 150K documents, which is most of my database. When I click in the link of this collection, it starts loading... then it stops and there is no error message. Just an empty collection.

There is no error in firestore-debug.log.

¯_(ツ)_/¯

---

P.S. The same procedure with a 3k entries and 1.3Mb file, worked.

Comment: Does this same process work with smaller sets of data with some complexity? ie. more than toy data but less than 50MB?

Comment: I have a very small file (40K) that worked fine. I think I will try to generate a 10Mb example.

Comment: The same problem happens with a 10k entries, 3.7Mb file. I will try a file bellow 1Mb.

Comment: The same process with a 1.3Mb set worked.

Comment: @FredGuth have you checked out if `firebase-debug.log` has any information as well? Also running Firebase emulator with the `--debug` flag will show the logs in the terminal. Finally, could you please share your Firebase structure, specially from the node where the data is not shown in the emulator?

Comment: Here is the firebase-debug.log: https://pastebin.com/EkjgZg5h
The collection `doctors` is the one that does not uploads (it seems), but there is also `appointments` collections.  In the debug log it seems that the error starts at appointments. What is strange is that it works in production.

Comment: @RogelioMonter, I have now a different problem that may be related to this one.  If I try to use the exported dump (folder in GCS bucket, ex. "10k") to import a dataset in BigQuery there is an error: "Does not contain valid backup metadata".  Now I am worried that if I need to use my backup, it wont work.

Comment: Do you mean you have solved the initial issue but now you have this other one? If that’s the case, please post the answer. For this other related issue, please create another post.

Comment: I haven't solved the first problem. I also have the problem with the BigQuery.  I think both problems are related.

Comment: Is it showing errors in the Dev/Browser console? As suggested by _yuchenshi_  [here,](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/4578#issuecomment-1162531308) a possible workaround would be exporting all relevant data using REST API / Node.js admin / Firestore JS SDK Lite and recreating the database from scratch, also restart the emulator (with no import) and continue the script from a clean start.